# VS2010 Debug web app causes "cannot start application" and "access denied" errors

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

When I try to debug my VS2010 web app (F5), the IE web browser windows pops up but then freezes, and my VS2010 IDE window pops up an error message:

> Unable to start program 'http://localhost:*nnnn*/Login.aspx'.
>   Access is denied.

I'm running VS2010 (10.0.30319.1), targeted to ASP.NET 4.0 (4.0.30319), in non-administrator mode, with ASP.NET debugging enabled, on 64-bit Windows 7 Enterprise SP1, with IE 9 (9.0.8112.16421 with update 9.0.29).

This web app and others I work with have been working just fine for several months, but they all started to misbehave in this manner a few weeks ago. At first, the first time I tried to debug (F5) I'd get the error, but after clearing it and closing the IE window and trying F5 again a second time, the browser would come up just fine. I assumed it was just some glitch, so I tolerated it.

Lately, though it has gotten worse, to the point that 90% of my attempts and re-attempts to debug the web app cause a hung browser and the error. It sometimes works, but most times it doesn't. I have to kill the handing iexplorer.exe processes to clean up my user space, otherwise I eventually get a message about not having enough files to start the browser. I try rebuilding, stopping the ASP.NET Development Server process, even exiting VS2010 and restarting it, but I can't seem to find the magic sequence of events to get it to work.

If I start *without* debug (Shift-F5), it works, but *two* IE web browser windows are opened, and both attach to the web app. I don't know if this is related to the first problem. And needless to say, this does not really allow me to debug my code. I tried attaching to either of the IE processes, but I still could not get the debugger to actually debug the executing app. (There is a message about no symbols being loaded for the attached process.)

Most of the solutions for this problem I've found say something about running with administrator access. I cannot do this, however; I work at a large financial company, and developers are **not allowed to have local admin rights** on our PCs. I don't control system patches, but I can request Help Desk ticket to resolve the problem; but I'd like to resolve this problem myself if it is a fairly simple configuration problem on my part.

**Addendum**

I should also add that I am *not* using IIS (because I don't have it installed on my system, and I can't use it anyway because I don't have local admin rights), but instead I am using the built-in Visual Studio Development Server. I've also selected a specific HTTP port number for it to use. Also, all of the directories I'm been using were created by me (as part of my project workspace), so there should be no access permission problems.

Like I said, I can *sometimes* get a debugging web session started, but most of the time I can't. So whatever is causing this problem, it is probably something intermittent.

Comment: Maybe [this table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj662724.aspx) will help - re: new code with "elevated permissions"? hth....

Comment: @EdSF - Thanks, that may help me a lot, esp. the link for "Debugging".

Answer (score 0):

This tend to occur when you try to run the full version of IIS rather than the Visual Studio Web Server or IIS Express. Have you tried running IIS Express instead? I think there's support for IIS Express that came with one of the later updates to VS 2010?

IIS proper definitely requires full admin rights in order to attach a debugger because full IIS runs under a system account rather than your own account. IIS Express (as well as the Visual Studio Web Server) however should run under your own user account and so debugging should work on the local machine even with a non-admin account.

One issue that might cause problems is directory permissions. Make sure that the folder where your Web files live are read/execute accessible through the file system for your user account.

Finally make sure you don't have some other instance of a Web service running on the same HTTP port.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm afraid that none of these apply to my situation. I've update the question above to show that a) I'm not using IIS, but the VS2010 built-in web server, b) have sufficient directory and file permissions, and c) no other web apps running.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue, it works when i don't choose to debug but CTRL+F5 to start it. F5 Debugger al